# combine different maven web-projects into a single project

Tags: javascript, maven

I want to combine more than 3 maven projects (HTML, javascript and CSS based) into a single one. My main project uses dependencies from other projects. So, how can I build a single project without changing those dependencies?

Comment: So you want to re-arrange your directory structure, or add the web projects's dependency to the mail project? or you want to add the web projects as module's to main project? please elaborate

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a multi module project with:

1. `mysite`: a parent pom module.
2. `mysite-core`:  a java module
3. `mysite-web`: a web resources module (javascript, html, ...)
4. `mysite-webapp`: a war module

`mysite` has `packaging pom` and includes the other 3 `modules`:

```
<groupId>mysite</groupId>
<artifactId>mysite</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
   <module>../mysite-core</module>
   <module>../mysite-web</module>
   <module>../mysite-webapp</module>
</modules>
```

`mysite-core` uses the standard `jar packaging`:

```
<parent>
   <artifactId>mysite</artifactId>
   <groupId>mysite</groupId>
   <relativePath>../mysite/</relativePath>
</parent>
<groupId>mysite</groupId>
<artifactId>mysite-core</artifactId>
```

`mysite-web` is similar:

```
...
<artifactId>mysite-web</artifactId>
```

`mysite-webapp` includes the java and the web resources module as a dependency:

```
...
<artifactId>mysite-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependency>
   <groupId>mysite</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysite-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysite</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysite-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With the [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) property from the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), you add the resources to the war:

```
<overlays>
   <overlay>
      <groupId>mysite</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysite-web</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
   </overlay>
</overlays>
```

**Note:** It is best to have a [flat project layout](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html), like:

- root

  - parent pom module
  - java pom module
  - java-1 jar module
  - java-2 jar module
  - web resources jar module
  - war module

instead of a hierarchical layout:

- root

  - parent pom module

    - java pom module
    - java-1 jar module
    - java-2 jar module
    - web resources jar module
    - war module

I've noticed that tools like Eclipse don't like hierarchical structures (slow or even endless builds).

Comment: Could you make this clear? At first, I've downvoted, then I made sense. 

Perhaps to try to come up with a more 'concrete' example e.g. `mysite[:pom]` -> (`mysite-core[:jar]`, `mysite-css[:war]`, `mysite-html[:war]`, `mysite-webapp[:war]`) and outlining the relationships especially in `mysite[:pom]` and `mysite-webapp[:war]`?

Comment: Thanks! But...

Not sure if the penultimate pom is semantically correct. mysite-core is being redefined as a war file and depending on itself

Comment: @aldrinleal: indeed, copy paste problems :) Changed it.

Comment: Nice job! Sorry for being a bit pedantic, but your answer was valid, but the explanation wasn't clear. Anyway, quite I'm fine for it (When mentioning `<overlays/>`, it helps to add a bit of context, from `<plugin/>` and below... Or perhaps a link to the m-w-p doc on overlays - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html - But I'm an annoying person :])

Actually, I'm going to bookmark and tell my users whenever they ask me some exoteric WAR deployment scenarios - e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298046/maven-separating-deployment-project/13625939#13625939 )

Answer (score -1):

Use Maven modules. There is extensive documentation here:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html