# Maven: Checkout a SVN Repository, compile, package into a jar and add as a Dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

We have a web application in which we are using Ant as a build tool. There is a urgent requirement to create web services (API) and this will be a separate project. For now, to make it available to our customers we have decided to use our web application and remove all unnecessary files (like velocity files, properties, xml etc) and make a jar of it. This jar will be used in our web service project.

In Maven, I want to checkout my web application svn branch, compile it, make a single jar of it and add as a dependency in my project. Is this possible? If yes, then please show me the way.

I'm new to Maven please explain your answers with more detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

- Get your .war deployed into a Maven Repository (local or remote) from your ant build
- Child Projects will embed your .war as a dependency, creating a war with your custom services + your original .war file
- It is advised that those Child Projects turn into an Archetype, so creating custom services gets easier

## Long Answer

From your SCM, you could modify your build.xml file and use [Maven Tasks for Ant](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/).

In particular, the [install and deploy](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html) examples are helpful in order to guide you on deployment your .war into a Maven repository (local or remote)

Then, a .war artifact (when accessible from a Repository) is able to be consumed from other .war applications.

Look into the maven-war-plugin Overlays Feature. In particular, this answer offers you more advice:

[combine different maven web-projects into a single project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100700/combine-different-maven-web-projects-into-a-single-project/14105957#comment19524174_14105957)

Other than that, I suggest you could also combine with Maven Archetypes (they're now easier than ever), so you could create skeleton projects for your webservices, already depending on this .war dependency.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I guess this is somewhat too difficult to understand and draw a solution from it. I will try hard to understand all this and find a solution from it.