# Adding more web-apps/wars to a Netbeans maven Enterprise Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans

I want to modularise my web application setup a bit better. I have a REST service that I want to put in its own web-app/war project. When you create a Maven Enterprise Application in Maven you get a project with an EAR, EJB and Web app archetypes. I want to add another Web app archetype where I can put my REST code to keep it separated from my regular web site code. So how do I do this?

Comment: Hmm, I created a new Maven Web Application and set it's location as the base directory of my Enterprise Application (the same location as the existing EAR, EJB and WEB projects) and it seems NetBeans has automatically added it as a module in my overall pom.xml. This is very nice if that is all that's required to add another Web app project, it seems like there has to be a catch...

Answer (score 0):

This question outlines the recommended way to merge multiple wars into a single one in Maven:

[combine different maven web-projects into a single project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100700/combine-different-maven-web-projects-into-a-single-project/14105957)

Perhaps it is what your looking for, right?